# Xamarin XAML: Setting Attached Property in Code

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a custom control with AbsoluteLayout attached properties:

```
        <common:FabImage
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1.0,1.0,-1,-1">
        </common:FabImage>
```

How can I set these properties in C# in the code so I can default them?

Comment: Is `FabImage` your custom control/code or a 3rd-party control?

Comment: The FAB Button image is a simple Floating Action Button I wrote for Xamarin Forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to set this in your `FabImage` cs code, which can be done like so:

```
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(this, new Rectangle(1.0, 1.0, -1, -1));
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(this, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);
```